# Query for unique IDs from a table if the IDs repeat for more than one values

Tags: sql

Here's the table I am dealing with -

Table Name: Filters

| Filter Type | Value | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| vendor | ABCS | 1001 |
| product | 109 | 1001 |
| vendor | BVHG | 1002 |
| product | 108 | 1003 |

And I need to pull out count of unique IDs that repeat in both vendor and product. Need help!

Tried using AND clause for filter criteria, but did not work

my attempt below -

```
Select ID from Filters
Where Filter_type = 'vendor' AND Filter_type = 'product'
```

Comment: So in the table above, the result should be 1001.

Comment: where's your attempt?

Comment: Updated in the question @MitchWheat

Answer (score 0):

The below query should give the desired result.
Please check.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) FROM filters WHERE filter_type IN ('vendor', 'product');
```

If you are looking for a list of unique ID values, you can remove the count.

```
SELECT DISTINCT id FROM filters WHERE filter_type IN ('vendor', 'product');
```

Answer (score 0):

To get all the IDs whose FILTER_TYPE is *vendor*:

```sql
select ID from FILTERS where FILTER_TYPE = 'vendor'
```

To get all the IDs whose FILTER_TYPE is *product*:

```sql
select ID from FILTERS where FILTER_TYPE = 'product'
```

To get the IDs that have both *vendor* and *product* FILTER_TYPE:

```sql
select ID from FILTERS where FILTER_TYPE = 'vendor'
intersect
select ID from FILTERS where FILTER_TYPE = 'product'
```

You want to retrieve the IDs that have both *vendor* and *product* FILTER_TYPE as well as the count for each of those IDs.

```sql
select ID, count(*)
  from FILTERS
 where ID in (
               select ID from FILTERS where FILTER_TYPE = 'vendor'
               intersect
               select ID from FILTERS where FILTER_TYPE = 'product'
             )
 group by ID
```

Refer to this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GzP7s894)

Note that you did not tag your [RDBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) so the "fiddle" uses SQL Server, however INTERSECT should work with most RDBMS's.